# ORA-40341: Access violation on model storage object in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

While I was trying to drop a table, it throws following error in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
ORA-40341: Access violation on model storage object
```

The tables are temporary tables created while pushing into the database using Oracle R Enterprise. The names of the tables are: `DM$PRORE$21_473, DM$PGORE$21_473, ...`

I need to drop all these tables as these tables have occupied large space of my database. While googling, I found this [link](http://ora-40341.db.quanti.cz/?errorSolveFormShowed=1&do=showSolveForm) but it provides no solution clues.

Comment: The error message advises you to contact your DBA or Oracle Support.  Have you done either?

Comment: `Cause:` An attempt was made to directly access/modify a schema object that stores model metadata and content.`Action:` Perform all mining operations (create,drop,alter, and select using data mining functions) against named model objects. Contact your DBA or Oracle Support if you suspect that an orphaned schema object.

Comment: Should I contact to DBA? As we donot have a dedicated DBA, I would like to do using some PL/SQL queries.

Comment: So you don't have a DBA.  And presumably you don't have an Oracle Support contract either.  That's tough. Oracle R is a very new technology, so there's really not that many people who know it.

Comment: It sounds like these tables are "owned" by a parent table, and they store various meta-data / structures to improve access performance. Try finding their "parent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database tables created using ore.push will have the prefix ORE$. Normally, these are automatically cleaned up when the R session ends or the ORE db connection terminated (unless you save the ore.frame objects in an ORE datastore).

In-database models from Oracle Data Mining (ODM)  as created from ore.odmSVM will also normally be deleted automatically and the end of the R session or ORE db connection termination. You should not attempt to remove DM$ tables as they are part of the in-database model. If you do delete any of these, their corresponding models will be corrupted/invalid.

You can invoke

```
SELECT name FROM dm_user_models;
```

to see the list of models in the database for your schema.

You can drop ODM models using the following in SQL*Plus or SQL Dev:

```
BEGIN 
  DBMS_DATA_MINING.DROP_MODEL('MY_MODEL'); 
END;
```

Lots of thanks goes to **Mark Hornick**, Senior Manager, Oracle Advanced Analytics for his constant support in ORE implementation in my project.